# Is it possible to use Ionic framework in my angularJs web app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using angularJs and JAVA for my web applications. so is it possible to use Ionic framework in it ? and if possible then how should I use it.

Comment: Ionic just a framework who needs angularjs to work perfectly

Comment: Ok so you mean if I am using angularJs then there is no need of ionic?

Comment: It's depend on your technology that you choose to work with. you can work with ionic css with jquery then you won't get the actual benifit of ionic as  every component of ionic is a directive which need angularjs to breathe .

Comment: Ok you are right, but what benifits i will get if I used Ionic with angularJs

Comment: You can use it's rich directives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic is a framework which is better to implement using angular js. It works as a directive but it needs angularJs.
Some pros of using Ionic are as follows:

1. Firstly Ionic is an HTML5 mobile app development framework targeted at building hybrid mobile apps. Hybrid apps are essentially small websites running in a browser shell in an app that have access to the native platform layer.
2. Ionic integrates into AngularJS hence helping structure that code better and more manageable.
3. Development of apps on leading mobile platforms (iOS, android, Windows) becomes possible and all the more facile with Ionic framework.

This are some of the things which i figured out from google.

For more details you can refer to following links :
[Ionic Framework](http://metadesignsolutions.in/5-benefits-using-ionic-framework-mobile-app-development-2/), 
[ionicframework.com](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html)

Comment: Thanks bro, I have implemented this framework to develop hybrid mobile applications, I found that ionic is better than phonegap and obviously we can develop attractive mobile applications when we use it with cordova to use native feature